# Change options in select with JavaScript without loosing chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to reload the options list of a select with JavaScript and JQuery, but I need to preserve previous chosen values.

This is my code:

```
    var temp = $('#SelectName').chosen().val();

    select = document.getElementById('SelectName');

    if (select.options.length > 0) {
        $('#SelectName').find('option').remove();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = result[i].myIdVariable;
        option.text = result[i].myTextVariable;
        select.appendChild(option); 
    }

    $('#SelectName').chosen(temp);

    $('#SelectName').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

With this code I loose all the chosen values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with this code:

```
var temp = $('#SelectName').val();

select = document.getElementById('SelectName');

if (select.options.length > 0) {
    $('#SelectName').find('option').remove();
}

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = result[i].myIdVariable;
    option.text = result[i].myTextVariable;
    select.appendChild(option); 
}

$('#SelectName').val(temp);

$('#SelectName').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

The difference is that now I use:

```
var temp = $('#SelectName').val();
```

and

```
$('#SelectName').val(temp);
```

previously:

```
var temp = $('#SelectName').chosen().val();
```

and

```
$('#SelectName').chosen(temp);
```